# Issue: Redefinition of Class

Tags: c++, xcode, redefinition

I am having troubles when I try to compile my program. The issues are that I have a "Redefinición of classes".

The .cpp code

```
#include "atmosfericConditions.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class clsPressure{     //Redefinition of "clsPressure"
    float pressure;
public:
    clsPressure(){}
    clsPressure(float presion){
        pressure = presion;
    }
    friend istream& operator >>(istream &i, clsPressure &e);
    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream &o, const clsPressure &s);
};

istream& operator >>(istream &i, clsPressure &e){
    char sign;
    i >> e.pressure >> sign >> sign;
    return i;
}

ostream& operator <<(ostream &o, const clsPressure &s){
    o << s.pressure << " Pa";
    return o;
}


class clsDensity{    //Redefinition of "clsDensity"
    float density;
public:
    clsDensity(){}
    clsDensity(float densdad){
        density = densdad;
    }
    friend istream& operator >>(istream &i, clsDensity &e);
    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream &o, const clsDensity &s);
};

istream& operator >>(istream &i, clsDensity &e){
    char sign;
    i >> e.density >> sign >> sign >> sign >> sign >> sign >> sign;
    return i;
}

ostream& operator <<(ostream &o, const clsDensity &s){
    o << s.density << " Kg/m^3";
    return o;
}


class clsSoundVelocity{    //Redefinition of "clsSoundVelocity"
    float soundVelocity;
public:
    clsSoundVelocity(){}
    clsSoundVelocity(float velocidadDelSonido){
        soundVelocity = velocidadDelSonido;
    }
    friend istream& operator >>(istream &i, clsSoundVelocity &e);
    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream &o, const clsSoundVelocity &s);
};

istream& operator >>(istream &i, clsSoundVelocity &e){
    char sign;
    i >> e.soundVelocity >> sign >> sign >> sign;
    return i;
}

ostream& operator <<(ostream &o, const clsSoundVelocity &s){
    o << s.soundVelocity << " m/s";
    return o;
}


class clsDynamicViscocity{    //Redefinition of "clsDynamicViscocity"
    double dynamicViscocity;
public:
    clsDynamicViscocity(){}
    clsDynamicViscocity(double viscocidadDinamica){
        dynamicViscocity = viscocidadDinamica;
    }
    friend istream& operator >>(istream &i, clsDynamicViscocity &e);
    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream &o, const clsDynamicViscocity &s);
};

istream& operator >>(istream &i, clsDynamicViscocity &e){
    char sign;
    i >> e.dynamicViscocity >> sign >> sign >> sign >> sign >> sign;
    return i;
}

ostream& operator <<(ostream &o, const clsDynamicViscocity &s){
    o << s.dynamicViscocity << " N/m^2";
    return o;
}
```

The .h code of the previous .cpp

```
//
//  atmosfericConditions.h
//  IASS Project
//
//  Created by Oscar Espinosa on 6/26/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 IPN ESIME Ticoman. All rights reserved.
//

#ifndef atmosfericConditions_h
#define ATMOSFERICCONDITIONS_H_

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class clsPressure{
    float pressure;
public:
    clsPressure(){}
    clsPressure(float presion){
        pressure = presion;
    }
    friend istream& operator >>(istream &i, clsPressure &e);
    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream &o, const clsPressure &s);
};
class clsDensity{
    float density;
public:
    clsDensity(){}
    clsDensity(float densdad){
        density = densdad;
    }
    friend istream& operator >>(istream &i, clsDensity &e);
    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream &o, const clsDensity &s);
};
class clsSoundVelocity{
    float soundVelocity;
public:
    clsSoundVelocity(){}
    clsSoundVelocity(float velocidadDelSonido){
        soundVelocity = velocidadDelSonido;
    }
    friend istream& operator >>(istream &i, clsSoundVelocity &e);
    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream &o, const clsSoundVelocity &s);
};
class clsDynamicViscocity{
    double dynamicViscocity;
public:
    clsDynamicViscocity(){}
    clsDynamicViscocity(double viscocidadDinamica){
        dynamicViscocity = viscocidadDinamica;
    }
    friend istream& operator >>(istream &i, clsDynamicViscocity &e);
    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream &o, const clsDynamicViscocity &s);
};

#endif
```

I can notice, that its the same code in the .cpp and .h .  I has been looking for some answer in  videos but I do not find nothing that can help me. I tried deleting the .cpp and leave only the .h, but it does not work.

As you can see, Xcode notifies me that the problem is in the classes of the .cpp.

Answer (score 1):

It is complaining because the same classes are defined twice.

You don't need to have the classes in both the .h and the .cpp files.  Put them in the .h and remove them from the .cpp file because the .cpp includes the .h file.

In the .CPP file, remove just the class definition, but leave the rest.  Your .cpp file should look like this:

```
#include "atmosfericConditions.h"

istream& operator >>(istream &i, clsPressure &e){
    char sign;
    i >> e.pressure >> sign >> sign;
    return i;
}

ostream& operator <<(ostream &o, const clsPressure &s){
    o << s.pressure << " Pa";
    return o;
}

istream& operator >>(istream &i, clsDensity &e){
    char sign;
    i >> e.density >> sign >> sign >> sign >> sign >> sign >> sign;
    return i;
}

ostream& operator <<(ostream &o, const clsDensity &s){
    o << s.density << " Kg/m^3";
    return o;
}

istream& operator >>(istream &i, clsSoundVelocity &e){
    char sign;
    i >> e.soundVelocity >> sign >> sign >> sign;
    return i;
}

ostream& operator <<(ostream &o, const clsSoundVelocity &s){
    o << s.soundVelocity << " m/s";
    return o;
}

istream& operator >>(istream &i, clsDynamicViscocity &e){
    char sign;
    i >> e.dynamicViscocity >> sign >> sign >> sign >> sign >> sign;
    return i;
}

ostream& operator <<(ostream &o, const clsDynamicViscocity &s){
    o << s.dynamicViscocity << " N/m^2";
    return o;
}
```

Comment: That works! And do you recommend using readers in this way, or is it better to keep the .cpp file where possible?

Comment: Recommendation is headers should contain only declarations  and .cpp file contains the  details.

Comment: It's just personal preference, but I try to have .cpp for classes that I expect to grow because you don't always want all of your code to be inline (meaning, defined inside the class definition).

Answer (score -1):

you can delete the class declaration .cpp file if it is duplicate. If they serve
different functionality then you may use a different namespace to get around the compilation error.